# Is there a function in R that does what atoi() does in C?

Tags: r, atoi

Is there a function in R that does what atoi() does in C?

More precisely that converts a character to an integer.

e.g. A = 65, P = 80 and so on ?

Comment: > as.integer("A")
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> as.integer(A)
Error: object 'A' not found

Comment: I think Julius means if there is a function which does the following `atoi("A") = 65`

Comment: Is that the standard use of atoi? I was under the impression that you passed a string that was representing a number into atoi to convert it to a numeric type.  It's been a while since I've used C though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`charToRaw` will give you the hex value. You can pass that to `as.numeric` to get the decimal equivalent

```
> as.numeric(charToRaw("A"))
[1] 65
> as.numeric(charToRaw("P"))
[1] 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Dasons' answer you can run this function:

```
atoi <- function(character){
  as.numeric(charToRaw(as(character, "character")))
}
```

and you can use it with numbers also `atoi(1) = 49`